# Serde: How to implement multiple custom sequences?

Tags: rust, traits, serde

So I'm writing a custom format to serialize/deserialize to/from a save game file format.

This question is me asking if my current approach is reasonable and what's the best way to solve this problem.

Since the design of the format is very questionable (despite being pretty widely used, paradox interactives save file format).

There are seemingly 3 forms of sequences.

In rising complexity we have:

#### Placeholder struct:

The formats are typically used with structs, so this will be the placeholder struct:

```rust
struct X { a:i64, b:String }
```

#### 1:

```
some_param={
    213 8450 23 1234 -21349
}
```

And with structs:

```
some_parameter={
    {
        a=123
        b="abc"
    }
    {
        a=-2
        b="asd"
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### 2:

```
some_parameter={
    0={
        a=3
        b="asdj"
    }
    1={
        a=-2
        b="fdgdd"
    }
    2={
        a=5
        b="uikpkcvd"
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### 3:

```
some_parameter={
    a=123
    b="abc"
}
some_parameter={
    a=12343
    b="ajbc"
}
some_parameter={
    a=122343
    b="abfac"
}
// ...
```

When thise format is used with primitives it looks like:

```
some_parameter=123
some_parameter=14523
some_parameter=122443
// ...
```

(I have not seen 3 used with primitives, but I can make a good guess how they should work considering the others)

#### My attempt

My attempt right now is to define my own structs which each represent one of the seqeunce forms.

E.g.

```rust
Struct Seq1<T> { data: Vec<T> }
Struct Seq2<T> { data: Vec<T> }
Struct Seq3<T> { data: Vec<T> }
```

And then write custom `impl<T> Serialize` for each (based off the standard sequence one [from here](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html)).

To handle indents I added an `indent` field to my definition of `Serializer`:

```rust
pub struct Serializer {
    output: String,
    indent: usize
}
```

My attempt for sequence form 2:

```rust
use serde::ser::{Serialize, SerializeSeq, SerializeMap};
use crate::ser::Serializer;

pub struct IDSeq<T> {
    data: Vec<T>
}
impl<T> Serialize for IDSeq<T>
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::ser::Serializer,
    {
        let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(self.data.len()))?;
        for (indx,e) in self.data.iter().enumerate() {
            serializer.output += "\t".repeat(serializer.indent) + format!("{}=",indx);
            seq.serialize_element(e)?;
        }
        seq.end()
    }
}
```

Currently this errors on `serializer.output`s and `serializer.indent`s with the errors:

```
no field `output` on type `S`
```

and

```
no field `indent` on type `S`
```

respectively.

Given the definition of `Serializer`:

```rust
pub struct Serializer {
    output: String,
    indent: usize
}
```

I think this is some issue to do with the trait `serde::ser::Serializer` vs the actual struct. I don't know how to fix this.

(ofc there is a bunch of additional code here I'm not showing, but I don't think it neccessary to illustrate the approach)

So I know this is quite a bit of an infomation dump, sorry for that.

Comment: If this is a "widely used" format, you might as well name it. In any case, the 3 "forms of sequences" don't appear that strange to me. 1 would be array-like, 2 would be map-like (with integer keys), and 3 just looks like your struct fields (same as map-like with string keys). So I don't think you need different sequence types to describe the format, I think you should just use the appropriate types (Vec, TreeMap/HashMap)

Comment: 2 being defined as a map would be bad, maps are unordered. The most effieicnt representation is simply a `Vec` an ordered list where the indicies are the IDs. Just all round better than using a map. 3 is awful, instead of using the sensible `y { x=[1,2,3,4], ...}` its `y { x=1,x=2,x=3,x=4, ...}`

Comment: If this format has a name or specification or anything that'd be very helpful.

Comment: 'If this format has a name' I've added where it comes from, but unfortunately its kinda inhouse at this company so it doesn't really have any public specification

Comment: `HashMap`s are unordered. Others like `BTreeMap` are ordered. But I'm not necessarily convinced that's a solution to your problem. Is it acceptable for the keys to be out of order in the file? (`{0="a" 2="b" 1="c"}`) Are gaps in the indices allowed? (`{0="a" 2="b" 3="c"}`) Do they have to start at 0?

Comment: @trentcl For form 2 they always cover the range 0..n (e.g. 0,1,2,3,...,n), they always appear in order in the file format as such I think it best they be serialized/deserialized in order.